# PetWorld - How do you unlock the map?

Tags: android, petworld-my-animal-rescue-premium

My kids have this game on their Kindles, PetWorld: My Animal Rescue Premium. One of the children's game has a map that shows a little picture of the animals and the other one does not have the map on their screen. It causes no end of fighting over who gets to play the kindle that has the map.

How do you unlock or get the map to show in this game?

Comment: Are both kindles running the same version of the game? Looks like the map was added back in March, so maybe one of them doesn't have auto-updates turned on?

Comment: I will check that and reinstall in on the one missing the map! Thanks!

Comment: The ones without the map had to start a new game for it to work.  @SaintWacko, can you update your comment to be an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Oh good, I'm glad that helped! I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the map was added back in March, so it's possible that the two tablets are running different versions of the game. Try updating/reinstalling the game on the tablet without the map.